# Problem when running multiple instances of the same form

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's the situation. I've been developing a serial communication application and I needed multiple instances of my main form to show up when I click on a `ListView` item. Everything was running fine before I added this code:

```
private void ListView_DeviceList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        ListViewHitTestInfo hit = ListView_DeviceList.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hit.Item != null)
        {
            Form m = new Form1();
            m.Show();
        }
}
```

After I tried to run it and double clicked in my `ListView` new instance of my form opened up as expected. The problem was they were glued together and I couldn't see the first one. After I closed it and tried to run it again it didn't show up. I could see the application running in the task manager and there was the icon in the windows taskbar but no UI opened up... Sorry this might be really unclear but I don't know how to describe it differently.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: Cause I need to work with multiple devices (they are all displayed in the `ListView`) at the same time hence I need multiple instances of my form...

Comment: No you don't. You need multiple instances of a child Form or UserControl. Maybe have a look into [MDI Child Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms). Or from start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications

Comment: Yes I would fix that but the problem is that my application doesn't work right now... When I try to run it nothing shows up as I said but I can see it running in the task manager and the application icon shows up in the taskbar but no UI opens up...

Comment: It sounds like a thread problem. Perhaps the main thread is bound to the initial form instance and when you close that, the thread aborts and thus the other instances all close too?

Comment: I tried debugging and there are no errors... My form starts but only appears in the taskbar, when i hover on it with my mouse it just shows a blank screen with no controls at all. Everything was fine before I tried running this code.

Comment: ...and if you comment out that block of code, does your application start magically working again?

Comment: With a double click, you're probably sending `Form1` under its Parent. Try with `m.Show(this);`.